# loquat tree or loquat?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> On the south end of the garden, in the shadows of a loquat tree, was
>   the servants' home, a modest little mud hut where Hassan lived with
>   his father. [Source](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1GnCrLgcyWwC&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%22in%20the%20shadows%20of%20a%20loquat%20tree%22&source=bl&ots=3yMv0b_cly&sig=KkN_d8ZCY5Fa4yuaZ3EZPijuryo&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9iIrdkPPKAhXDD5AKHQP_BhwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20shadows%20of%20a%20loquat%20tree%22&f=false)

I would like to know if is possible to use the word loquat in the place of 'loquat tree' keeping the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, provided that "tree" isn't part of the name of the plant, it isn't necessary, though it can be helpful.

[Loquats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loquat) are just that... "tree" is not part of their name.

> The loquat (Eriobotrya japonica) is a species of flowering plant in the family Rosaceae, native to south-central China. It is a large evergreen shrub or small tree, grown commercially for its yellow fruit, and also cultivated as an ornamental plant.

As you can see from the description, the loquat is either a tree or a shrub, depending on its growth, so in this case, excluding "tree" since it may be a shrub, may actually be better... or, if you want to emphasize that it's a tall tree-like loquat, you might specifically want to include it.

> I'll be waiting under the big loquat tree at the back, not the bushy ones near the front of the garden.

If it doesn't matter and it's the only plant of its kind in the yard, "loquat" alone should be just fine:

> My dad has several loquats in his yard, which produce delicious fruits in the summer.